# how can I add a "read more" tag directly in the template?

Tags: templates, shortcode, read-more

how can I add a <--more--> tag directly in the template? I mean, the exact php code to use in a template for that shortcode. I need it for a script that makes use of that shortcode to hide content and having to add the "more" shortcode by hand through all the posts would be such a task

any help appreciated!

Comment: Afaik, `<!--more-->` is no _shortcode_. Anyway: You can trigger [shortcodes by code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would probably be something like this:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}\" class=\"more-link\">".__( 'Read more &gt;', 'your-theme' ). '</a>';
```

Check out the source on how WordPress does it: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L219

This has to be inside the loop to work and the `$post` global has to be visible in the current scope.

Comment: that's exactly what I ws looking for, many thanx!!!